# Can I access a CursorLoader within a CursorAdapter Button OnClickListener?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-button, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a list of items in an Android activity. I want users to be able to reorder the list by clicking buttons on the list item that then update a weight value within an SQLite database. The list is populated from a CursorLoader.

I have implemented a solution that doesn't use the CursorLoader. This means that the weight value changes but doesn't refresh the CursorLoader. The list order doesn't refresh until the list activity is restarted.

This is the code in the CursorAdapter that calls the function to adjust the weight when the button is clicked.

```
    final int rowID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Storage.COLUMN_ID));

    Button upButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_edit_move_up);
    upButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Storage store = new Storage(v.getContext());
            store.increaseActivityWeight(rowID);
        }
    });
```

This is the function in the Storage SQLiteOpenHelper class that changes the weight.

```
public void increaseActivityWeight(int activityID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String[] d = { };
    Cursor c;
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, weight FROM activity WHERE _id = "+activityID, d); 

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int oldWeight = c.getInt(1);
        int newWeight = oldWeight + 1;

        ContentValues cvSelectedActivity = new ContentValues();
        cvSelectedActivity.put("weight",Integer.toString(newWeight)); 

        db.update(Storage.ACTIVITY_TABLE_NAME, cvSelectedActivity, "_id "+"="+activityID, null);

                    // EDIT: The following code is incomplete. It needs to identify a displaced activity by weight and swap it's weight with that of the old activity. 
        int displacedActivityID = c.getInt(0);
        ContentValues cvDisplacedActivity = new ContentValues();
        cvDisplacedActivity.put("weight",Integer.toString(newWeight)); 

        db.update(Storage.ACTIVITY_TABLE_NAME, cvDisplacedActivity, "_id "+"="+displacedActivityID, null);
    }

    db.close(); 
    c.close();
}
```

This initiates the CursorLoader and orders the list in the ListActivity.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { Storage.COLUMN_ID, Storage.ACTIVITY_NAME, Storage.WEIGHT }; 
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            ActivityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, Storage.WEIGHT);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

Is there a way to access the CursorLoader within the CursorAdapter? Can I add  implements
`LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` to the CursorAdapter?

I saw this tutorial that offers an alternative solution. 
http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html 
I started implementing it this way but changed to the custom CursorAdapter. I can't remember why.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(ActivityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null)` in `increaseActivityWeight()` to notify the list about update?

Comment: Thanks ookami.kb. I put `context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(ActivityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null)` in the `upButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`. It is now refreshing.